# Compact $C \subset$ Jordan-measurable $A$ such that $\int_{A-C} 1 < \epsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This question is (3-22) in M. Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds.

If $A$ is a Jordan-measurable set and $\epsilon > 0$ show that there is a compact Jordan-measurable set $C \subset A$ such that $\int_{A-C}1 < \epsilon$.

Intuitively, I can see why this would be true. Without considering pathological examples immediately, I think: If $A$ is Jordan-measurable then it must be bounded. We could take a closed set $C \subset A$ and for each point $x$ on the boundary of $C$, reduce the distance between $x$ and the boundary of $A$ until it is sufficiently small at each point. In other words, "expand" $C$ while staying inside of $A$ until $C$ is "big enough" for our claim to hold.

I am troubled, however, trying to prove the statement rigourously. Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this problem #3-22 out of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds book?

Comment: @bryanj Yes, I have updated the question to include this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the material in that section?

Comment: @bryanj This is my first encounter with the material. I am reading this book as a self-study.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A definition of Jordan-measurable given in Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* is that the set is bounded, and the boundary (which is everything except the open interior and open exterior) has measure zero.

Let $B$ be the interior of the Jordan-measurable set $A$. Then $B$ is open. Cover the boundary of $A$ with *open* rectangles whose total volume is no more than $\epsilon$.
Let $U$ be the union of these open rectangles, so $U$ is open. Let $E$ be the exterior of $A$. Let $C$ be the complement (in the ambient space) of $E \cup U$. Then $C$ is contained in $A$. To see why, let $x \in C$ (which in fact might be empty). Certainly $x \notin E$. $x$ is also not in $U$, and so is not in the boundary of $A$, which is contained in $U$. The ambient space is partitioned into the interior, the exterior, and the boundary of $A$, so $x$ is in $B \subseteq A$.

Since $C$ is contained in $A$, it is bounded, and it is also the complement of an open set, so it's compact.

Finally, $A - C$ is contained in $U$, which is the union of the rectangles covering the boundary of $A$. This shows the Jordan measure of $A - C$ is no more than $\epsilon$.

**Detail:** Because $A$ is bounded, it's easy to see that the boundary of $A$ is also bounded. The boundary of $A$ is also closed (complement of the interior and exterior). So the boundary of $A$ is compact. Then the open cover of the boundary by rectangles can be taken to be a *finite* cover (boundary is *content* zero). This means that $U$ is the union of a finite collection of open rectangles. To show that $A - C$ is Jordan-measurable, so that your integral exists, notice that $A - C = A \cap U$. Then use the fact that $Boundary(X \cup Y)$, $Boundary(X \cap Y) \subset Boundary(X) \cup Boundary(Y)$, to show the boundary of $A - C$ has measure zero.

**EDIT:** We have to show that $C$ is Jordan measurable.

A set and its complement have the same boundary, so $A - C = A \cap \tilde C$ and $\tilde A \cup C$ have the same boundary.
$C = A \cap ( \tilde A \cup C)$, so $\partial C \subset \partial A \cup \partial ( \tilde A \cup C) = \partial A \cup \partial (A-C)$.
$\partial C \subset \partial A \cup \partial (A-C)$ shows that the boundary of $C$ has measure zero.

Comment: It's been a long time but now that I'm working through Spivak I encountered your answer. You don't seem to prove that $C$ is Jordan measurable, why is it true?

Comment: @Fanni : Yep looks like I forgot that part. I made an edit to the answer, and I believe it's correct. You might want to double-check yourself. The idea is that the boundary of an intersection is contained in the *union* of the boundaries.

Comment: How can you show that there is such a C and it is also the finite union of aligned rectangles?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the result of Problem 3-21 in the book.

> Problem 3-21.
> If $A$ is a closed rectangle, show that $C\subset A$ is Jordan-measurable if and only if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a partition $P$ of $A$ such that $\sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_1}} v(S) - \sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_2}} v(S)<\varepsilon$, where $\mathcal{S_1}$ consists of all subrectangles intersecting $C$ and $\mathcal{S_2}$ all subrectangles contained in $C$.

Let $B$ be a closed rectangle which contains $A$.
Let $\varepsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number.
By Problem 3-21, there is a partition $P$ of $B$ such that $\sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_1}} v(S) - \sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_2}} v(S)<\varepsilon$, where $\mathcal{S_1}$ consists of all subrectangles intersecting $A$ and $\mathcal{S_2}$ all subrectangles contained in $A$.
Let $C=\bigcup_{S\in\mathcal{S_2}}S$.
Obviously, $C$ is a compact Jordan-measurable set which is contained in $A$.
It is obvious that $\int_{A-C}1=\int_B\chi_{A-C}\leq U(\chi_{A-C},P)=\sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_1}-\mathcal{S_2}}v(S)<\varepsilon$ holds.

By the way, [I tried to solve Problem 3-21.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4804193/1226161) (But I don't know if my solution is right.)