# Problem 3-21 in "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

The following problem is Problem 3-21 in "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

I solved this problem but I am not sure if my solution is right. Is my solution right? If so, how to improve my solution? If not so, please tell me where my solution is wrong.

> Problem 3-21.
> If $A$ is a closed rectangle, show that $C\subset A$ is Jordan-measurable if and only if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a partition $P$ of $A$ such that $\sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_1}} v(S) - \sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_2}} v(S)<\varepsilon$, where $\mathcal{S_1}$ consists of all subrectangles intersecting $C$ and $\mathcal{S_2}$ all subrectangles contained in $C$.

Let $A=[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times [a_n,b_n]\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.
Suppose $C\subset A$ is Jordan-measurable.
The boundary of $C$ has measure $0$.
Since $C$ is bounded, the boundary of $C$ is also bounded.
Since the boundary of a set is closed, the boundary of $C$ is closed.
So, the boundary of $C$ is compact.
So, the boundary of $C$ has content $0$.
There is a cover $\{U_1,\dots,U_m\}$ of the boundary of $C$ such that $v(U_1)+\cdots+v(U_m)<\varepsilon$.
Let $U_i=[a_{i1},b_{i1}]\times\cdots\times [a_{in},b_{in}]$.
Let $l=\max\{b_1-a_1,\dots,b_n-a_n\}$.
Since a polynomial function is continuous, there is $k\in\{1,2,\dots\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m\prod_{j=1}^n (b_{ij}-a_{ij}+2\frac{l}{k})<\varepsilon$.
Suppose $k\in\{1,2,\dots\}$ is a positive integer such that $\sum_{i=1}^m\prod_{j=1}^n (b_{ij}-a_{ij}+2\frac{l}{k})<\varepsilon$.
For each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, let $P_i$ be the partition of $[a_i,b_i]$ into $k$ equal subintervals.
$P=(P_1,\dots,P_n)$ is a partition of $A$.
If $S\in\mathcal{S_1}-\mathcal{S_2}$, then $S$ contains a point in $C$ and a point in $\mathbb{R}^n-C$.
Since $S$ is connected, $S$ contains a point $x$ in the boundary of $C$.
Since $\{U_1,\dots,U_m\}$ is a cover of the boundary of $C$, $x\in U_i$ for some $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$.
Obviously, $S\subset [a_{i1}-\frac{l}{k},b_{i1}+\frac{l}{k}]\times\cdots\times [a_{in}-\frac{l}{k},b_{in}+\frac{l}{k}]$. (Note that it is possible there is no $i\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ such that $S\subset U_i$ even if $S\in\mathcal{S_1}-\mathcal{S_2}$.)
So, $\sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_1}-\mathcal{S_2}}v(S)=\sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_1}}v(S)-\sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_2}}v(S)\leq\sum_{i=1}^m\prod_{j=1}^n (b_{ij}-a_{ij}+2\frac{l}{k})<\varepsilon$.

---

Conversely suppose there is a partition $P$ of $A$ such that for $\varepsilon>0$, $\sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_1}}v(S)-\sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_2}}v(S)<\varepsilon$.
Let $\varepsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number.
Suppose $A$ is a partition of $P$ such that $\sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_1}}v(S)-\sum_{S\in\mathcal{S_2}}v(S)<\varepsilon$.
Let $x$ be a point in the boundary of $C$.
It is easy to check there is a subrectangle $S$ of $P$ such that $x\in S$ and $S\cap C\neq\varnothing$ and $S\cap (\mathbb{R}^n-C)\neq\varnothing$.
Let $\{U_1,\dots,U_m\}$ be a collection such that $\mathcal{S_1}-\mathcal{S_2}=\{U_1,\dots,U_m\}$.
$\{U_1,\dots,U_m\}$ is a cover of the boundary of $C$ and $v(U_1)+\cdots+v(U_m)<\varepsilon$ holds.